# Insert and delete multiple div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I know how to add div dynamically when button click, and how to delete that div using jQuery:

```
<input type="button" class="adddiv" value="add" />
  <div class="clean">
      msg 
    <button class="close" value="close" >
  </div>

<script>
  $(".adddiv").on("click",function(){
     $('.clean').after('<div class="clean main1">msg<button class="close" value="close" /></div>');
  });

 $(document).on("click",".close",function(){
    $(this).closest('div').remove();
 });

</script>
```

But here I need to make restrict maximum number of clean div in the page is 5 . If user add more than 5 div i need to restrict .

How to do this ?

Comment: You want to restrict the user to adding only five new '.clean' `<div>` elements, so there can be six in total (including the element that's present on page-load)? Incidentally none of the `<div>` elements you're adding seem to have a 'close' button at all, is that deliberate?

Comment: yes. Total 6 in the webpage

Comment: @DavidThomas could you please give a working example that can add and delete div  . in jsfiddle ? . also i need to increment the class name when adding like main1,main2,main3 etc.

Comment: I've just posted an answer, though not addressing the incremented `main` class (although this seems redundant, if you want to track which element was added where you'd be better off using a `data-*` attribute, such as `data-index`, otherwise you have to retrieve that index by parsing the class-names, which is far more awkward than is necessary).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest the following, though note that I chose to add the 'indexing' to a custom `data-*` attribute, in this case `data-index`, since it avoids the necessity of parsing the element's class-names to retrieve that index; the `data-index` values can be retrieved either with plain JavaScript:

```
var index = HTMLElement.dataset.index;
```

Or through jQuery:

```
var index = $(element).data('index');
```

That said, my proposed solution:

```
// using the on() method to bind the anonymous function
// of that method as the event-handler for the 'click'
// event fired on the '.adddiv' element:
$('.adddiv').on('click', function() {

  // caching the current '.clean' elements present on
  // the page:
  var cleans = $('.clean'),

  // cloning the first of those elements, including
  // descendants, data and event-handlers, using
  // clone(true, true):
    newClean = $('.clean').eq(0).clone(true, true),

  // retrieving the number of '.clean' elements
  // currently in the document:
    num = cleans.length;

  // setting the 'adddiv' <input> element to be
  // disabled if after the next addition (which
  // is completed within this function) there
  // will be more than 6 '.clean' elements in
  // the document:
  this.disabled = num + 1 >= 6;

  // if the current number of '.clean' elements
  // is less than 6:
  if (num < 6) {

    newClean
      // adding the value of the 'data-index' attribute,
      // JavaScript is zero-indexed so the new index is
      // equal to the current number of 'clean' elements:
      .attr('data-index', num)

      // and then we insert the cloned element after the
      // last of the current '.clean' elements present
      // in the document:
      .insertAfter(cleans.eq(num - 1));
  }
});

// using on() again to bind clicks on the elements
// matched by the supplied selector, delegating the
// event-listening to the document (although the
// closest ancestor element present in the page
// would be a better choice):
$(document).on('click', '.clean > .close', function() {

  // removing the closest ancestor <div> element of
  // the clicked button:
  $(this).closest('div').remove();

  // caching the '.clean' elements in the document
  // after removing the unwanted element:
  var clean = $('.clean');

  // iterating over each of the (remaining) '.clean'
  // elements and updating the 'data-index' property
  // to be equal to the index of insertion:
  clean.attr('data-index', function(i) {

    // it seems likely that the first of the elements
    // should have no index (from what I can see in
    // the question, therefore if i (the index of
    // the current element in the collection) is equal
    // to zero we return an empty string, otherwise we
    // return the index:
    return i === 0 ? '' : i;
  });

  // updating the disabled property of the '.adddiv'
  // <input> element, to reenable if the current
  // number of 'clean' <div> elements is less than 6
  // (though because we enable an element by updating
  // its disabled property it does look a little
  // confusing and 'backwards' almost):
  $('.adddiv').prop('disabled', $('.clean').length >= 6);
});
```

```js
$('.adddiv').on('click', function() {
  var cleans = $('.clean'),
    newClean = $('.clean').eq(0).clone(true, true),
    num = cleans.length;
  this.disabled = num + 1 >= 6;

  if (num < 6) {
    newClean.attr('data-index', num).insertAfter(cleans.eq(num - 1));
  }
});

$(document).on('click', '.clean > .close', function() {
  $(this).closest('div').remove();

  var clean = $('.clean');
  clean.attr('data-index', function(i) {
    return i === 0 ? '' : i;
  });

  $('.adddiv').prop('disabled', clean.length >= 6);
});
```

```css
/* hiding the close button if there is
   only one <div> present within the
   common parent */
div:only-of-type button.close {
  display: none;
}

[data-index]::after {
  content: attr(data-index);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="adddiv" value="add" />
<div class="clean">
  msg
  <button class="close">Close</button>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5a0w3zvj/).

References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).
- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
- [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: I've just updated the answer to include the indexing you wanted, though please note that I'm using the `data-index` attribute rather than an incremented class-name which is substantially more awkward to retrieve than a custom `data-*` attribute, which can be retrieved with either `HTMLElement.dataset.index` or with jQuery: `$(element).data('index')`

Comment: The code you write now is too complicated to understand . Why there is no after() function .?

Comment: and what i will do if i want to display the number of that div in msg . That when user add first div then msg is msg1.Adding second then msg is msg2 etc ?

Comment: This is one of the best js code for this problem. Sorry for my previous comments . Now i understand the code . Thank you @david

Comment: I can only apologise for the way I write code, but I write to my preferred style and standard (which is entirely a matter of personal, subject opinion).  Incidentally if you'd like to remove those earlier comments for which you're apologising you can simply hover over them with your mouse and then click on the rounded delete icon (an 'x' in a greyed-out circle). You don't have to, if you'd rather not.

Comment: friend i have some doubts . (1) i need to display the msg with the number of div . for example msg1 for the first div that added by the user , msg2 for the second div . etc . How to do this ?

Comment: Rather than incrementally adding requirements in comments please take a few moments and edit your question, that way everyone that views the question knows exactly what you're wanting as a result. I don't mind adding more details but I'd prefer to know precisely what details you're wanting before I update again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <input type="button" class="adddiv" value="add" />
  <div class="clean">
      msg 

  </div>
  <button class="close" value="close" > Remove </button>




$(".adddiv").on("click",function(){
if($('div.main1').length <= 5){

$('.clean').append('<div class="clean main1">msg<button class="close" value="close" /></div>'); 
}
else{
 // do something else here
 alert($('div.main1').length)
}
 });

$(document).on("click",".close",function(){
    $(this).closest('div').remove();
 });
```

Check it out on [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Wisdomabioye/xwoh4e7y/1/)

Answer (score 0):

On every 'add' event - you can iterate on .clean div's using $.each() loop and count how many clean divs is added. Then if there's 5 already, you don't add any more div's. Check: https://api.jquery.com/each/

Example:

```
var counter = 0;
$('div.main1').each( function() {
    counter++;
});
if(counter >= 5) {
    // do nothing
}
else {
    // add next div
    $('.clean').after('<div class="clean main1">msg<button class="close" value="close" /></div>');
}
```

Comment: could you please give a working example that can add and delete div  . in jsfiddle ? . also i need to increment the class name when adding like main1,main2,main3 etc.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer having the html-template in the dom instead of a string within the javascript code.
This is the result.

I'd suggest not using a css className based on the amount of items, because one might delete number '2' out of 5 and add a new one, which would get another number '5'. Number '5' will then be duplicate.

```js
$(function() {
  var $wrapper = $('#clean-wrapper'),
      $addButton = $wrapper.find('.adddiv'),
      $itemToClone = $wrapper.find('.itemToClone');

  // Add new div.
  $addButton.on('click', function() {
    $itemToClone
    .clone()
    .appendTo($wrapper)
    .show();

    $wrapper.trigger('mutation');
  });

  // Close div.
  $wrapper.on('click', '.close', function() {
    var $item = $(this).parents('.clean').first();
    $item.remove();

    $wrapper.trigger('mutation');
  });

  // Toggle button.
  $wrapper.on('mutation', function() {
    var itemCount = $(this).find('.clean:visible').length;
    $addButton.prop('disabled', itemCount >= 5);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clean-wrapper">
  <input type="button" class="adddiv" value="add" />
  <div class="clean itemToClone" style="display: none;">msg <button class="close" value="close"  /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

**HTML Code:**

```
<input type="button" class="adddiv" value="add" />
  <br/>
  <div class="clean">
      msg 
     <br/>
    <input type="button" class="close" value="close" />
  </div>
```

**JS Code:**

```
<script>
        $(".adddiv").on("click",function(){
          console.log($('div.clean').length);
        if($('div.clean').length <= 4){
          console.log("Test");
          $('div.clean').last().after('<div class="clean">msg <br/><input type="button" class="close" value="close" /></div>'); 
        }
        else{
         // do something else here
        }
         });

        $(document).on("click",".close",function(){
            if($('div.clean').length>1)
            $(this).closest('div').remove();
         });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following codes. Simplest solution:

```
   <div id="main_container">
        <div class="clean">
            Message
            <button class="close">CLOSE</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $("#adddiv").on("click",function(){
            $('#main_container').append('<div class="clean">Message<button class="close">CLOSE</button></div>');
        });

        $(document).on("click",".close",function(){
            $(this).closest('.clean').remove();
        });

    </script>
```